# Setting variable using data from a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with the last line of the code.  I believe the problem is in how I'm setting my range but I'm lost on how else to set it.  I'm trying to do error checking by making sure all the fields in a user form were filled in before continuing on in the macro.

```
Dim emptyRowNumber As Long
emptyRowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Leads").Range("a:a")) + 1
.
.
.
Dim filledCount As Integer
filledCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Leads").Range(Cells(emptyRowNumber, 1), Cells(emptyRowNumber, 11)))
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], please take a [tour], check [ask] and provide [mcve].  If you encounter an error, please also provide the full error message.

Comment: Is `Leads` not the active sheet? Add `Sheets("Leads").` before both instances of `Cells()`.  Also, what's happening, do you get an error? If so, what error, where?

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify all cells and ranges inside a range statement to the same worksheet.

In this code sample `Cells(emptyRowNumber, 1)` and `Cells(emptyRowNumber, 11)` refer to cells on the ActiveSheet not the cells of `Sheets("Leads")`.

> Sheets("Leads").Range(Cells(emptyRowNumber, 1), Cells(emptyRowNumber, 11))

Personal preference I group all variable at the top of my procedures alphabetically by datatype (numbers, strings, objects... ect.).  I also recommend using `With` statements to shorten your code.

```
Dim emptyRowNumber As Long, filledCount As Integer

With Sheets("Leads")
    emptyRowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("a:a")) + 1
    filledCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(emptyRowNumber, 1), .Cells(emptyRowNumber, 11)))
End With
```

Comment: Beautiful.  I'm teaching myself VBA so there are things I know I don't do efficiently.  Thanks.

Comment: You should watch this series on Youtube: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)